# Where to find prebuilt binaries for subversion 1.6 for Ubuntu (or Debian)?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, debian

While I can easily find the binaries for the latest version of subversion (1.6) I can't find the binaries for Ubuntu (or Debian).

The [download page](http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#ubuntu) at tigris.org suggest to use the command:

```
apt-get install subversion
```

but as you can experience this will install up to the version 1.5.4 (at the time of writing May 6, 2009).

This isn't a nice thing because many working copies that I share with Windows are automatically updated to 1.6 by TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Is it really that hard to just compile it yourself?

Comment: @Zifre: Yes it is, for example see http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2008-05/1316.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find certified binaries here, now: http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads?type=ubuntu910

The script will setup a repository for you, so you will keep on getting updates.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an APT repository with Subversion 1.6 binary packages for Ubuntu 8.04 through 9.10: https://launchpad.net/~anders-kaseorg/+archive/subversion-1.6

Comment: broken, complains about no public keys

Comment: open the link in your browser you'll find the key on that page.

Answer (score 10):

I solved it with these repositories:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/anders-kaseorg/subversion-1.6/ubuntu intrepid main`
`deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/anders-kaseorg/subversion-1.6/ubuntu intrepid main`

Comment: Will this Ubuntu repository also work safely on Debian stable? I'm particularly looking for the Apache2 svn module since I want to upgrade my svn server to 1.6.

Comment: Where are the PGP keys for the packages? I cannot find them.

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://launchpad.net/~anders-kaseorg/%2Barchive/subversion-1.6l to install the package.
Recall that you can authenticate the PPA in Ubuntu using the signing key (from the site: 1024R/413576CB). In this case, the terminal command to add the key is:
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 413576CB`

Answer (score 6):

You can find a debian package for subversion 1.6 in the experimental repositories from debian at http://packages.debian.org/experimental/subversion.

Having said that you would probably be alright working with version 1.5.4 from the ubuntu repositories, if the svn server you are using isn't running 1.6 you won't be able to use any of the new features in the client anyway.

If I was you I would first try to use the version in the repositories before installing it from a third party as you may find that it does work for you and it will make your life easier when it comes to updating subversion in the long run.

Comment: Note that it may be necessary to rebuild the experimental packages from source (using dpkg-buildpackage), as they may be built against a newer version of glibc.

Comment: Thanks but this method will require the installation of many other experimental dependencies that I don't want install.

Comment: Do you really think that using an "experimental" package that will upgrade also the Apache HTTPD to the "experimental" version notwithstanding I need only the client will make my life easier?

Comment: Third party? The CollabNet are the creators of Subversion the piece of software that I need.

Answer (score 4):

Add these two lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/anders-kaseorg/subversion-1.6/ubuntu hardy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/anders-kaseorg/subversion-1.6/ubuntu hardy main
```

Get Anders key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 413576CB
```

Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Upgrade or Install:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

(Via [GVS](http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/installing-subversion-svn-1-6-ubuntu-8-04-lts-hardy))

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Here the solution.

From the CollabNet download [page](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/redhat.html) download the binaries for Red Hat.
Then use alien for installing it, for example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install alien
$ sudo alien CollabNetSubversion-client-1.6.2-1.i386.rpm
$ sudo dpkg -i collabnetsubversion-client_1.6.2-2_i386.deb
```

Beware that the command is installed under /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/svn not in /usr/bin/svn. So after that simply put this line in your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Don't do that, use the packages from experimental.

Comment: @Marek: Why are you suggesting this? First of all I'm scared by the "experimental" word :) ... And in any case doing that it would install many other experimental revision of other important packages (like Apache).

Comment: Due to the various distributions setting up their systems differently packages from other distributions can mess up your system.  Alien isn't smart enough to pick up on these difference and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @mlowen: it's generally true but, please, note that in this case the 'aliened' package is from Collabnet and not from another distribution and that the installation of the subversion package from Collabnet is quite independent from the rest of the system: in fact nothing is integrated and all files are under /opt/CollabNet_Subversion. In this case there is nothing to adjust because nothing is integrated. This is not a issue for my case.

Comment: Using alien to get a package in debian should be the ultimate last resource.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* the 1.6 version to work with your Windows working copies. SVN is clever enough to recognise the features provided by clients, and only allow those features through - so your 1.5.4 client can connect to your 1.6 server without any problem; as can your Windows 1.6 client.

The only time you'll have problems here is if you're using 2 clients with a single working copy - ie your Windows and Linux clients both commit and update a single, shared directory. Such an arrangement is a bad idea anyway, you'll have all kinds of problems even without counting EOL differences. If you have such a situation, checkout a new WC, so you have one for Linux and another for Windows.

Comment: -1 for two reasons:

 2. I regularly works with working directories shared between Windows and Linux and I never found any problem related to EOL differences. If you don't use special properties Subversion simply leaves the EOL character(s) that it found. Any decent Linux and Windows editor can handle both EOL styles.

 1. As I specified I need 1.6 because I want to use the updated version of TortoiseSVN which uses the 1.6 subversion libraries.

Comment: well, it wasn't that clear that you had a single WC for both OS. I doubt that's a common case.

Comment: Sharing a working copy between Windows and Linux has in the past been considered a Wrong Thing To Do. Not sure what the latest is now, but this post says it mostly comes down to EOL issues now: http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=70227

I'd still say that sharing a working copy is an unnecessary way to work, given the opportunities for other workflows that Subversion makes possible.

Comment: you can also have multiple client on the same (linux) platform.
at least this is the case with eclipse (subclipse-plugin)