# libapache2-svn, matching version with Subversion 1.6.1

Tags: svn, ubuntu, module, apache2, apt-get

I'm installing subversion on an Xubuntu desktop system with apache2 installed and running fine. However, I wanted to use Subversion 1.6 because of the sparse directory feature. I'm running Jaunty, but I was able to tell apt-get to download 1.6.1 by temporarily adding the software source "deb http://source archive.canonical.com/ubuntu karmic main" and removing the regular "jaunty" source from the list.

However, it seems that Ubuntu's karmic distribution installs subversion 1.6.1 fine, but when it gets to apache2lib-svn it installs 1.5.4 rather than 1.6.1. What can I do to remedy this? I'm trying to use apt-get remove since I know it cleans up packages of what you've installed, and being relatively new to Linux I figured it's better not to leave random packages lying around without a home.

Comment: Somewhat duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831723/where-to-find-prebuilt-binaries-for-subversion-1-6-for-ubuntu-or-debian

Comment: I have read that entry, as well as many others, but I feel that my question is a little more specific. I have found a nice pre-built binary of subversion already--on canonical's own servers. But now I need an updated libapache2-svn module.

Comment: However, I do appreciate you taking the time to post Milen, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My PPA has a [backport of Karmic’s subversion 1.6.5 packages](https://launchpad.net/~anders-kaseorg/+archive/subversion-1.6) to Hardy, Intrepid, and Jaunty, including libapache2-svn.  See also this [backport request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/382048).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu desktop, so I found the solution would be to disable all the standard Ubuntu repositories in Synaptic, then add "deb http://packages.debian.org/squeeze". Squeeze is the test release, and has Subversion v1.6.3 and libapache2-svn v1.6.3. Then you can apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn to your heart's content.